# Can I use an background alert with framework7?

Tags: android, cordova, html-framework-7

I am writing and app with Framework7, I want it to send an alert notification at some time even if the app has quitted.

Is that possible

Comment: It's possible to implement a background service(class Service) that shows an alert notification. Although the app has to be in idle/sleep mode or in the background or foreground. As soon as the app is put on hold for instance by an user in the settings the background service is put on hold as well.

Comment: Maybe this one can help https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push